# how to put password to my application

Tags: android

I have wrote another application, now it is store only my private data. Whenever user click on the application icon, as you know, application will start. I want to put password before the my application is starting up. If user will write password incorrectly, at most 5 times, application will not start.

My question is ; how can I put password and do not let my application to start if incorrect pass given ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main activity should provide a prompt to enter the password. The password box should be an `EditText` with the password property set (to make the characters hidden when typing in it). You should also have a submit `Button` which will check the password for the one you have stored. You should have a counter which will increment to 5 as each wrongly typed password is entered. When it reaches 5, you can use `finish()` to kill the activity (`finish()` is called on the `Activity` you're using). If they type the correct password, you can launch an `Intent` to start another `Activity` which will be your actual application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the user for the password as soon as the application icon is started, so the first thing your applicatin should do is ask for the authentication.

So, in the MainActivity (the first activity which gets called when the application starts),

```
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            passwordCounter = 0;
            //ask the user for the password using a non-cancellable Dialog
            //get the input in an EditText


            //when the Submit button is clicked after entering the password, do the following
            if(password does not match && passwordCounter < 5)
              {
                 passwordCounter++;
                //ask the user for the password once again using the non-cancellable Dialog
              }
             else if (password does not match && passwordCounter >= 5)
             {
                finish(); // kill your Activity

             }
             else
             {
                //start the actual functioning of the application
             }
}
```